# Can I cast FloatingActionButton to ImageButton in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

My app has a floating-action-button, but it needs to support KitKat (API 19). For the floating-action-button, I use an `ImageButton` by default and swap it (in the layout) for the real `FloatingActionButton`for API 21 or higher.

In my activity, I have the code to get the fab as this...

```
ImageButton mAddProject;

...

mAddProject = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.new_project_fab);
```

Of course, this works fine in Android 20 or lower, but when being run in Android 21 or higher, it throws an error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton
```

The [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) says that `FloatingActionButton` is extended from `ImageButton`. I imagine this would allow me to cast it to `ImageButton`. I guess I'm wrong and don't understand how casting works.

Is it possible to cast `FloatingActionButton` to `ImageButton`?

Comment: What you describe seems impossible. `FloatingActionButton` comes from the design support library that you bundle with your app, it does not come from the framework. So it's implementation cannot depend on the API version of the device. In my application I am casting `FloatingActionButton` to `ImageButton` and it works for me on API 22.

Answer (score 2):

#### Explanation

The casting is actually working. It just is that the button does not exist yet. I think that the following code should work:

```
FloatingActionButton mAddProject = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.new_project_fab);
ImageButton mAddProjectImageButton = (ImageButton) mAddProject
```

Since this code won't run below API 19, I suggest the following:

#### Suggestion

I would suggest that you add the button programmatically. You should check the version and whenever it is API21+, you add the FAB. Whenever it is 20-, you add the ImageButton. This way you are sure that you have the correct button working for the correct API.

#### Example:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    // Add the FAB button
} else{
    // Add the ImageButton
}
```